# Codeigniter- Pagination-showing empty data after delete/edit

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am listing the registered employee from the db and showing 10 employee per page. I'm using codeigniter pagination for the purpose.

If I deleted an employee in page 2, after deleting I need to go to page 2 showing rest of the employees in page 2.

View:

```
<a href="<?php echo $path;?>welcome/delete_employee/employeeid/<?php echo $row->empID;?>/pageNum/<?php echo $currentPage; ?>" onClick="return delAlert()";><img src="<?php echo $path;?>/img/delete.png" height="30px" width="30px" /></a>
```

Controller:

```
public function delete_employee()
        {


            $session_id = $this->session->userdata('logged_in');                

                if($session_id) {


                $array = $this->uri->uri_to_assoc(3);
                $count=$array['pageNum']-1;
                $i=$count*10;

                $this->load->model('welcomemodel','m',true);
                $this->m->deleteemployee($array['employeeid']);



                     $config = array();
                    $config["base_url"] = base_url() . "welcome/employee";
                    $config["total_rows"] =$this->m->employee_count();
                    $config["per_page"] = 10;
                    $config["uri_segment"] = $array['pageNum'];







                    $data['showData'] = $this->m->getEmployee($config["per_page"], $i);

                    $this->pagination->initialize($config);
                    $data["links"] = $this->pagination->create_links();
                    $data["currentPage"] =$array['pageNum'];


                    $this->load->view('header');
                    $this->load->view('employee',$data);    




                } else {

                    $this->load->view('session_expired');

                }



        }
```

Model:

```
public function deleteemployee($employeeid)
         {
             $this->db->where('empID',$employeeid);
        $this->db->delete('employee');
        return $this->db->affected_rows();

    }
 public function getEmployee($limit, $start)
 {
    $this->db->limit($limit, $start);

    $this->db->select()
              ->from('employee')
              ->order_by('emp_fname');

     $this->db->join('service', 'employee.serviceID = service.serviceID','left');
    $query=$this->db->get();

return $query;


 }

  public function employee_count()
   {
      return $this->db->count_all("employee");
   }
```

But now the pagination link shows first page's link,even though contents of second page is displayed....

Comment: `$page = ($this->uri->segment(3)) ? $this->uri->segment(3) : 0;` is wrong. Third segment is your employee id, not your page number.

Comment: @ AdrienXL 
I edited my code and contents are displaying but showing incorrect pagination link.Pagination link of first page shown even though contents of second page displayed after deleting :(

Answer (score 0):

**model method**

```
public function employee_count()
{
    $result = $this->db->get('employee');
    if ($result->num_rows() > 0) {
        //employee record available 
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        // employee record not available
        return false; 

    }
}
```

**View**

```
<?php
     $getData = $this->[your model name]->getEmployee($limit, $start);
?>

<?php if ($getData): ?>
    //Your Pagination Part Here.....
<?php else: ?>
    // else Nothing
<?php endif ?>
```